# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp

Tags: centos

```
[root@ bncsutil]# make
g++  -Wall -O3 -I ../ -Wno-multichar -fPIC -shared -lgmp bsha1.o cdkeydecoder.o checkrevision.o decodekey.o file.o libinfo.o oldauth.o nls.o pe.o sha1.o stack.o -o libbncsutil.so
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lgmp
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [libbncsutil.so] Error 1
```

I try to do this in centos-6-x86-devel.
Gmp is already installed. Seems like something wrong with path, but i don't know what exactly do.

Comment: Probably you need to install gmp-devel as well to get access to the linkable library.

Comment: libgmp3-dev on Linux Mint

Answer (score 71):

```
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
```

Did the trick for me.(for Ubuntu)

Comment: That probably won't work on the centos system the original question referenced

Comment: Yes but it would at least give you a hint of the name of the lib to look for.

Comment: This is needed by the ruby bcrypt gem

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem with Centos:

`yum install gmp-devel.x86_64`

fixed it for me for eventmachine ruby gem that would not install. Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the problem was that `LIBRARY_PATH` was not correctly set to the directory containing libgmp.